# How do I update a UIlabel from Popup View Using Separate View Controller

Tags: swift

Kinda new to Swift programming and have a question regarding updating an existing uilabel from a popup view. I followed this tutorial:

[YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S5i8n_bqblE)

I have a main ViewController named 'myViewController' and a Popup View controller named 'popUp'.
On myViewController I have 1 x UILabel which is an outlet:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel?
```

this label is populated in viewDidLoad:

```
myLabel.text = "hello"
```

On the popUp View controller I have 6 Buttons. Each button has a IBAction:

```
  @IBAction func button1(_ sender: Any) {

//how do I set the uilabel from here to myViewController

dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Im presenting the popUp like this:

[Storyboard Segue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDvWZ.png)

I would like to be able to bring up the popUp controller and select a UIbutton, it would automatically dismiss and update the label on the 1st viewcontroller. I can get everything working expect updating the UIlabel.

hope that makes sense

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example you could use notifications or a protocol and let you main view controller know when a button has been pressed on the popup controller.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotificationcenter

https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html

Comment: Hello, I got it working from this answer. thank you

Comment: no problem, glad to help. please click on accept (this answer) if this works for you. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can create functions inside of myViewController that will get called when a button is pressed:

    //this would be in myViewController

    var labelText: String?
   // in viewDidLoad() 
    if myLabel.text != nil { 
    myLabel.text 
    } else { 
    myLabel.text = "hello" 
    } 
    func changeLabelToSayFoo() { 
    self.labelText = "Foo" 
    }

    //this would be for the button in the pop up controller
    @IBAction func button1(_ sender: Any) {

    myViewController.changeLabelToSayFoo()

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: Hello, I tried this way earlier but I get the following error. **Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**

Comment: ok, that makes sense. What about setting a value for the text in myViewController

    var labelText: String?


then in viewDidLoad()
    if myLabel.text != nil {   
    myLabel.text
    } else {
    myLabel.Text = "hello"
    }


change the changeLabelToSayFoo to be 

func changeLabelToSayFoo() {
self.labelText = "Foo"
}